# App doesn't present modally, but crashes with `Application tried to present modally an active controller`

Tags: ios

I have been looking at this for days now and I cannot figure out what is going on.

I have this crash affecting 2% of users per day (across iPad & iPhone, not limited to iOS 12, full stack-trace at the bottom):
`Application tried to present modally an active controller <DownloadViewController: 0x10a0c3c00>.`

Nowhere in my code do I call `UIViewController presentViewController:animated`, and there are no modal segues to `DownloadViewController`. There's always a `UINavigationController` present (it's the initial VC of the storyboard).

I tried simulating race-conditions where segues are performed twice, or where a `UIAlertController` is left displayed after the `UIViewController` under it has disappeared and it attempts to perform a segue to the active VC, but I cannot reproduce this crash: the most I can cause is the `DownloadViewController` to get pushed onto the `UINavigationController` twice (not the end of the world and no crash).

This crash started happening after I added some `UIAlertController`s so i'm assuming they have something to do with it, but I cannot figure out how.

Any ideas where to go next?

---

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2201b0518 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x21f38b9f8 objc_exception_throw
2  UIKitCore                      0x24c01859c -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:]
3  UIKitCore                      0x24c01aa7c __63-[UIViewController _presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke
4  UIKitCore                      0x24c033570 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator _applyBlocks:releaseBlocks:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x24c02f930 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext _runAlongsideCompletions]
6  UIKitCore                      0x24c02f608 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x24ca2ba00 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x24ca02758 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x24ca02d2c -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x24ca02dcc -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
11 QuartzCore                     0x22464f958 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x21fbf17d4 _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x21fb9f004 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
14 CoreFoundation                 0x220141ec0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x22013cdf8 __CFRunLoopRun
16 CoreFoundation                 0x22013c354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
17 GraphicsServices               0x22233c79c GSEventRunModal
18 UIKitCore                      0x24c5afb68 UIApplicationMain
19 WeDownload                     0x100ea1f40 main (main.m:14)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x21fc028e0 start
```

Comment: what's `UIAlertController` do? Does the action have something to do with this `DownloadViewController`?

Comment: It can performSegue from a VC before DownloadViewController to it. The segue is a show segue - uses the UINavigationController

Comment: what action leads to this crash?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash

Comment: ... red herring, wasn't the keyboard animation after all, but I am getting closer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it. The issue was that inside a block like this:

`[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{`

... I was effectively calling `[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];` twice in a row (where alert was a UIAlertController).

**Most important learning**: in the error message `Application tried to present modally an active controller <DownloadViewController: 0x10a0c3c00>`, DownloadViewController is the *presenter* not the thing being presented. I would have figured this out days sooner if i'd understood that error message correctly.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed important and worth repeating: The view controller in the error message is the view controller that tried to present an already active view controller, not the view controller that was already active.

Comment: Note that the wording has been improved in the iOS 14 SDK: `Application tried to present modally a view controller <UITableViewController: 0x7ff91080a700> that has a parent view controller <UINavigationController: 0x7ff91000f000>.`

Comment: @JordanH , hi can you solve this? I got this error today!!